# A problem about matrix eigenvalues: the eigenvalues of $A_n$ are all positive and no more than $3+2\sqrt 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Today I was asked by a friend to have a look over a linear algebra problem, which is quite easy at a first glance:

> For $n\in\mathbb N$, put $$A_n=\left[\begin{matrix}1 &\frac{1}{2} &\frac{1}{3} &\cdots &\frac{1}{n}\\
> \frac{1}{2} &\frac{1}{2} &\frac{1}{3} &\cdots &\frac{1}{n}\\
> \frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{3} &\cdots &\frac{1}{n}\\
> \vdots& & &\ddots & \vdots\\
> \frac{1}{n}& \frac{1}{n}& \frac{1}{n}& \cdots &\frac{1}{n}\end{matrix}\right].$$ Then the eigenvalues of $A_n$ are all positive and no more than $3+2\sqrt2$.

To the positivity of eigenvalues, we may consider the matrix $P=\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ -1 & 1\\ & \ddots&  \ddots \\& & & 1\\& & & -1 &1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and it follows that $P^\top AP=\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1/2 \\ & 1/6& &\ast \\ & &\ddots\\ & &  & 1/(n-1)n\\ & O& & & 1/n\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Now the problem is, the wierd bound $3+2\sqrt 2$ cannot be seen. Diagonalizing this real symmetric matrix does not seem to work because it usually needs the eigenvalues beforehand. I thought about Gerschgorin disk but unfortunately it does no help here. So I would like to ask for some ideas about this problem, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that the equality $\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^2=3+2\sqrt2$.

Comment: It is well know that the spectral radius equals $\lim \limits_{k\to \infty}\left(\left\Vert \left(A_n\right)^{k}\right\Vert\right)^{1/k}$ for any matrix norm. And since [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Max_norm) (I didn't bother checking
) taking the maximum entry is a matrix norm, I'm stumped as to what I'm surely missing.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos So can we see any possible approach that leads to this equality?

Comment: @GitGud Yes, spectral radius formula and $\infty$-norm are well-known, but how are they related to this problem?

Comment: This has been asked before (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2082200) but received no answers. By the way, the matrix is $A_n=DLL^TD$, where $D=diag(1,1/2,\ldots,1/n)$ and $L$ is the lower triangular part of the all-one matrix.

Comment: @user1551 Good to know that! But could you please elaborate a little more what happens next after knowing its square root?

Comment: I am not taking square root of $A_n$. It's a Cholesky decomposition. It is mentioned here just as a quick way to see why $A_n$ is positive definite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually all the eigenvalues of $A_n$ are less than $4$ [see Section V of Man-Duen Choi's paper Tricks or Treats with the Hilbert Matrix, *American Mathematical Monthly* 90 (1983), 301-312]. Because $3 + 2 \sqrt{2} \approx 5.8$, the claimed result is correct but is not the best possible upper bound of the eigenvalues of $A_n$.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering!